# Store Parameters in place OTHER than config.js

Tags: javascript, parameters, protractor

I'm using parameters for some iterative E2E tests using Protractor/Jasmine. I've seen in other articles that parameters are normally stored in `config.js`.

Now my parameters file is going to be big, BIG and I'd rather not have it as part of `config.js`. Can I use a separate file e.g. `parameters.js`? How would I call these in the spec files?

NB: the contents of the parameters will be x-paths. Here's a quick e.g

```
//baths
module.exports = {
params: {

product: {
 category: ".//*[@id='baths']",
 model: ".//*[@id='wilson-app']/main/floorplan/discovery-catalogue/product-list/section/div/product[1]/div/kf-button[2]/button",
```

etc, etc

Thanks
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use native module.exports/exports - require syntax:

```
protractor.conf.js:

exports.config = {
    ... some other config
    params: require('params.js').params

    ... some other config
}
```

then in

```
params.js:

exports.params = {
    product: {
        category: ".//*[@id='baths']",
        model: ".//*[@id='wilson-app']/main/floorplan/discovery-catalogue/product-list/section/div/product[1]/div/kf-button[2]/button",
        foo: 'bar'
    }
}
```